# RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration

Tags: python, runtime-error

This is my code:

```
import os
import collections
def make_dictionary(train_dir):
    emails=[os.path.join(train_dir,f) for f in os.listdir(train_dir)]
    all_words=[]
    for mail in emails:
        with open(mail) as m:
            for i,line in enumerate(m):
                if i==2: #Body of email is only 3rd line of text file 
                    words=line.split()
                    all_words+=words
    dictionary=collections.Counter(all_words)
    # Paste code for non-word removal here(code snippet is given below)
    list_to_remove=dictionary.keys()
    for item in list_to_remove:
        if item.isalpha()==False:
            del dictionary[item]
        elif len(item)==1:
            del dictionary[item]
    dictionary=dictionary.mostcommon[3000]
    print (dictionary)

make_dictionary('G:\Engineering\Projects\Python\Documents\enron1\ham')
```

I am receiving the error "RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration" on writing this code. I have
only text files in the directory. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: change `list_to_remove=dictionary.keys()` to `list_to_remove=[k for k in dictionary]` to avoid *associating* the `list` of `keys` to the `dict` so that changes done in the `dict` are not reflected back to the `list`

Comment: Thanks. It works. @Ev.Kounis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this two code snippets:

```
d = {1: 1, 2: 2}
f = [x for x in d]
del d[1]
print(f)  # [1, 2]
```

and:

```
d = {1: 1, 2: 2}
f = d.keys()
del d[1]
print(f)  # dict_keys([2])
```

As you can see, in the first one the dictionary `d` and the list `f` are not related to one another; changes in the dict are not reflected to the list.

On the second snippet, due to the way we create the list `f` it remains *linked* to the dict so deleting elements of the dict also *removes* them from the list.

Both behaviors might be somewhere helpful but in your scenario it is the first one you want.